# Saved delta file reads as an df - is it still part of delta lake?

Tags: pyspark, hive, databricks, delta-lake, data-lakehouse

I have problems understanding the concept of delta lake. Example:

1. I read a parquet file:

   `taxi_df = (spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/mnt/randomcontainer/taxirides.parquet"))`
2. Then I save it using asTable:

   `taxi_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("taxi_managed_table")`
3. I read the just stored managed table:

   `taxi_read_from_managed_table = (spark.read.format("delta").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/taxi_managed_table/"))`
4. ... and when I check the type it shows "pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame", not deltaTable:

   `type(taxi_read_from_managed_table)`  # returns pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
5. Only after I transform it explicitly using the following command, I receive the type DeltaTable

   `taxi_delta_table = DeltaTable.convertToDelta(spark,"parquet.`dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/taxismallmanagedtable/`")`

   `type(taxi_delta_table)`   #returns delta.tables.DeltaTable

/////////////////////////////

Does that mean that the table in stage 4. is not a delta table and won’t provide the automatic optimizations provided by delta lake?

How do you establish if something is part of the delta lake or not?

I understand that delta live tables only work with delta.tables.DeltaTables, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `spark.read...load()` - it returns the Spark's DataFrame object that you can use to process the data. Under the hood this DataFrame use the Delta Lake table. `DataFrame` is abstracting the data source so you can work with different sources and apply the same operations.

On other hand, `DeltaTable` is a specific object that allows to apply only Delta-specific operations.   You even don't need to perform `convertToDelta` to get it - just use `DeltaTable.forPath` or `DeltaTable.forName` functions to obtain its instance.

P.S. if you saved data with `.saveAsTable(my_name)`, then you don't need to use `.load`, just use `spark.read.table(my_name)`.